# Allow free input in bootstrap-tags input (Objects as tags)

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-tags-input

I am using bootstrap-tags input (Objects as tags) for my tags input. It's work fine with typehead js auto complete suggestions as official document said [Objects as tags](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/). But this only allows suggested tags as input, in other word, only those which are in Json list. I trying to allow freeinputs along with suggested tags from the list with default value (example: stackoverflow Tags). But I couldn't able to do it right.
Here is my code:

```
var cities = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('text'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            local: citilist //{value: 1, text: "Saint Lucia", continent: "Ararat"}... 
        });

        cities.initialize();
        var elt = $('#txt');
        elt.tagsinput({
            itemValue: 'value',
            itemText: 'text',
            typeaheadjs: {
                name: 'cities',
                displayKey: 'text',
                source: cities.ttAdapter()
            },
            freeInput: true
        });
        elt.tagsinput('add', { "value": 1, "text": "Amsterdam", "continent": "Europe" });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You can try this code. It's work for me. Please write this with your existing code.

```
var count = 0; 
$('body').on('keydown', '.tt-input', function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 9) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#your-tag-input-Id').tagsinput('add', { 
      value: --count, 
      text: $('.tt-input').val(), 
      continent: "Unsaved" 
    }); 

    $('.tt-input').val("");
  }
});
```

> negative value is new added tag and positive value is suggested tags.
>
> `'.tt-input'` is text box `$('#txt')` class.

**Edit: Suggesting `count--` to `--count` (-1 first, then return value), so that `value`'s of free inputs start at -1**

Comment: You genius, very easy and simple solution. Thanks